# AttributeError: module ‘streamlit’ has no attribute ‘metric’

Tags: python, streamlit

I am using streamlit `metric` module in my web app but it results in a attribute error.
like this one:
AttributeError: module `streamlit` has no attribute `metric`

I am using `streamlit version : 0.62.0`

windows : 32 bit os

python version : 3.7.1

My code snip:

```
def weather_forcast():

 obs = mgr.weather_at_place(location)
 weather = obs.weather

 temp = weather.temperature(unit=units)['temp']

 st.metric(label='Temperature', value=temp)

 print(f"Temperature: {round(temp)}{sign}C")
 cloud = weather.clouds
 print(f"Clouds Coverage: {cloud}%")
 wind = weather.wind()['speed']
 print(f"Wind Speed: {wind}m/s")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `metric` method for streamlit version 0.62. You can confirm by checking out the version documentation [here](https://docs.streamlit.io/en/0.62.0/api.html). I suggest you upgrade streamlit module to the latest if you have to.